# Java possibly requiring unnecessary extends keyword in PECS construction

Tags: java, sonarlint, pecs

I have a code example where Java forces me to use the `extends` keyword on a class that is final in a PECS construction. I do not understand why exactly. The code can be found below or at https://onecompiler.com/java/3yvf4g97f. The compiler fails to compile method named `process`. If I remove method `process` then SonarLint will trigger a violation of rule https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4968 for method named `processPecs`. Which seems reasonable, or is this a false positive? Is there a better approach for "processing arbitrary data"? Do I need to suppress SonarLint's warning here and file a bug report for SonarLint?

```
import java.util.List;

class PecsTest {
  static final class DataContainer<D> {
  
      final D data;
      
      public DataContainer(D data) {
          this.data = data;
      }    
  
      D getData() {
          return data;
      }
  }
  
  static class Processor<D> {
  
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      List<DataContainer<D>> processPecs(List<? extends DataContainer<? super D>> list) {
        return (List<DataContainer<D>>) list;
      }
      
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      List<DataContainer<D>> process(List<DataContainer<? super D>> list) {
        return (List<DataContainer<D>>) list;
      }
  }
  
  static class Data {
  }
  
  static class ExtendedData extends Data {
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Processor<Data>().processPecs(List.of(new DataContainer<>(new ExtendedData())));
    new Processor<ExtendedData>().processPecs(List.of(new DataContainer<>(new Data())));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DataContainer<ExtendedData>` is not assignable to `DataContainer<Data>`. But since `DataContainer` is a producer, it makes sense to use `? extends Data` here (the PE in PECS), as both types can produce a value of type `Data`:

```java
DataContainer<ExtendedData> a = new DataContainer<>(new ExtendedData());
DataContainer<Data> b = new DataContainer<>(new Data());

DataContainer<? extends Data> a2 = a, b2 = b;

Data d1 = a2.getData(), d2 = b2.getData();
```

---

In other words, both, `DataContainer<ExtendedData>` and `DataContainer<Data>`, are *subtypes* of `DataContainer<? extends Data>`. The fact that the class `DataContainer` is `final` is irrelevant.

So, the Sonar warning is wrong here. Suggesting to avoid final classes as upper bound only makes sense if the final class is not generic.

---

The same reasoning about `DataContainer<ExtendedData>` not being assignable to `DataContainer<Data>` despite `ExtendedData` is a subclass of `Data` applies to a `List` of generic types.

`DataContainer<ExtendedData>` is a subtype of `DataContainer<? extends Data>` but a `List<DataContainer<ExtendedData>` is not assignable to `List<DataContainer<? extends Data>>`.

You have to resort to `? extends` when the list acts as a producer, i.e. allows you to get `DataContainer<? extends Data>` elements from it.

```java
List<DataContainer<ExtendedData>> list1
    = Collections.singletonList(new DataContainer<>(new ExtendedData()));
List<DataContainer<Data>> list2
    = Collections.singletonList(new DataContainer<>(new Data()));

// List<DataContainer<? extends Data>> list3 = list1; // does not compile
// List<DataContainer<? extends Data>> list4 = list2; // neither does this

// both lists can act as producer of DataContainer<? extends Data>
List<? extends DataContainer<? extends Data>> list3 = list1; 
Data d3 = list3.get(0).getData();
List<? extends DataContainer<? extends Data>> list4 = list2;
Data d4 = list4.get(0).getData();
```

Note that since `DataContainer<Data>` and `DataContainer<ExtendedData>` are distinct types, neither being a subtype of the other, there is no way to define a common consumer type for `List<DataContainer<Data>>` and `List<DataContainer<ExtendedData>>` that allows to add elements of both types.

---

Keep in mind that with invocation type inference, results may seem to contradict these rules at the first glance. For example, when you write

```java
List<DataContainer<Data>> list
    = Collections.singletonList(new DataContainer<>(new ExtendedData()));
```

you get no error. Not because you can add a `DataContainer<ExtendedData>` to a `List<DataContainer<Data>` but because in this case, the compiler inferred `DataContainer<Data>` as the type to construct. And passing an instance of `ExtendedData` to the constructor of `DataContainer<Data>` is valid.